# dynamic disable select box with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make an html select box which dynamically disables and enables based on what the user select in a different select box... This was working fine when I used just html, but I would like to use the jQuery plugin Chosen for this, and it is not working... The main thing I need dynamic chosen to be disabled or enabled based on the onchange for the other select box. Is this possible with chosen? And how? Thanks so much.

**Old Code : *Workin*g**

```
<script>
function myDisable() {
a=1;
b=3;
    for (i=1;i<3;i++){
          posi=a+b*i;
          document.getElementById('drop'+posi).disabled = true;
} } 
</script>
```

**New code with PHP : Not Working**

```
<script>
function myDisable() {
a=<?php echo $angka; ?>;   // a variable number for id select box
b=<?php echo $fields; ?>;  // b variable number of many fields table
j=<?php echo $jp; ?>;      // j variable number of select boxes that will disable 
    for (i=1;i<j;i++){
          posi=a+b*i;
          document.getElementById('drop'+posi).disabled = true;
} } 
</script>
```

**PHP select box looping +/- 50 :**

```
<select name="modul[]" id="drop<?php echo $angka ?>" onchange="fetch_select<?php echo $random ?>(this.value); check(this); myDisable();">
           <option value="0">Lanjutan</option>
           <?php
             include 'include/conn.php';
             $select=mysql_db_query(@$db,"select nama_modul,jp from modul where nama_pelatihan='$nama_pelatihan'",@$koneksi);
             while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
             {
                 $jp=$row['jp'];
              echo "<option value='".$row['nama_modul']."'>".$row['nama_modul']."(".$row['jp'].")</option>";
             }
           ?>
         </select>
```

Comment: Make sure that you generate valid ids.

Comment: Important note about `include/conn.php` -  You indicate that block is looping +/- 50 times, and assuming that's where your database connection is made, you are then reconnecting to the database 50 times, which will quickly use up the server's allotted connections causing a fatal error, or at least use up vast resources needlessly. Move the `include/conn.php` outside any loop, typically connections are made once at the start of the script.

Comment: Here full sample source :
http://pastebin.com/E35iBEhg
a = number of id
b = number of filed table
j = hours = number of disable select box

@MichaelBerkowski

Comment: You already have the `include/conn.php` included at the top. It must be removed from the loop.

Comment: why removed include/conn.php ??
look the sample code. save php format.
and run - work . . .

but if used variable php . . . 
a=<?php echo $angka; ?>; 
b=<?php echo $fields; ?>; 
j=<?php echo $jp; ?>;
Not Work for me . . .

Comment: Can you help me sir @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: As I explained in the first comment, you already had include/conn.php at the start of the script. By placing that in the loop, it would make a new database connection for each loop iteration, and that may use up server connections and crash the script.

Comment: Since you are mixing PHP & JS, you must view the browser's page source to see if the PHP values have been placed into the JS correctly to begin with, debug JS errors, and debug PHP errors.  At the start of the PHP, always when developing & testing add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I do not do looping in include/conn.php. 
I also have done a bug report, and all running normally, but does not run as my desire . . . whats wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Try executing a call to `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");` after the `for` loop just before exiting the `myDisable()` function. In your case `#form_field` will be some selector that identifies your html select box element. Chosen might need to redraw itself to reflect the updated options and this is how we can tell it to do that.

Comment: Here full sample source : http://pastebin.com/E35iBEhg  a = number of id. b = number of filed table. j = hours = number of disable select box.